# Firebase "sign in method is disabled" despite having enabled it

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am configuring my login page for my app, and trying to add a section where users can connect to firebase... Im trying to use firebase auth to sign up new users, but I get this error when running this code

```
 if (newRegistrationEmail.text != "" && newRegistrationUsername.text != "" && newRegistrationPassword.text != "" && newRegistrationRepeatedPassword.text != "")
 {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: newRegistrationEmail.text!, password: newRegistrationPassword.text!, completion: 
    {
       user, error in

       if error != nil {
            print(error)
       }
```

The error:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17006 "The given sign-in
>   provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the
>   Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The given sign-in provider is
>   disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console,
>   under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.,
>   error_name=ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED})

I've checked my Firebase console, and I have the email option enabled, so Im not sure why it won't let me use email in my code. Any ideas on how to fix it?? Thanks so much!!

Comment: The most likely cause is that the code is authenticating against a different project than the one where you enabled email+password authentication.

Answer (score 7):

Just had the same issue. I was trying to add to an existing Firebase project, so I skipped all of the setup steps under the assumption that my project would just work because it was already enabled. Here's what worked for me:

1. Delete the GoogleService-Info.plist file in your project folder.
2. On Firebase, navigate to your project's Settings page.
3. Re-download GoogleService-Info.plist
4. Drag it into your project folder.

Hope this helps! This was a super frustrating error!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I forgot enable Auth Facebook in firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be using an older Firebase SDK. If you are using cocoa pods, add the following to your Podfile.

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Fabric'
```

After you add the pods, in your terminal type:

```
pod update
```

[Click here for more explanation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/189)

[Click this link for setup and to get the latest sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Also make sure you have GoogleService-info.plist in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to **create an app in Firebase** project.
Go to settings -> Project Settings -> 'Your Apps' or something like that -> create an app (choose from Android, iOS, Web, etc.), copy all the configs and you got it. Btw, I had a web project.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue in Android. Cleaning and rebuilding the project resolved the issue.